# How to fix bright pixels around light sources?

Tags: mesh

I'm working on a scene in blender and i have applied emission to a plane as main light source(which is located on the right hand side) and also emission coming from the tip of the candle light object. However when i render it i get these orange dots around the candle emission as you can see in the image. I have tried to up the sampling but they are always there. Any ways to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are called **fireflies**, and there are several easy ways to get rid of them. **Fireflies** are often present in low-light renders. The following are the three easiest.

### Clamping

This is probably easiest and best way to combat fireflies. Turn the *Properties panel > Render tab > Sampling drop down > Clamp Indirect:* value to *3*.

[image]

### Filter Glossy

Turn the *Properties panel > Render tab > Light Paths drop down > Filter Glossy:* value to *0.5*. This blurs all reflective/refractive elements just a bit.

[image]

### Samples

Sometimes you just need more samples.

All ideas and images from [here](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/).

Comment: Thanks, i always wondered what filter glossy was for anyway!

Comment: I just tried this but saw no difference, any more advice?

Comment: @Ulus Can you add a .blend file to your question or comment it? Those should have worked, and if they didn't, I can try some other stuff once I have the file.

Comment: How can I attach .blend file? :)

Comment: Upload one to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com). Is a free, long term site made specifically for blender stack exchange.